# How to change page title in Magento "Magento Commerce"?

Tags: magento2, page-title

When I click on a link **send to a friend** and want to send the link to some of my friend I have the title **Magento Commerce** displayed in my title tag.

The question is: how to change it to something else?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can change the default page title in the admin panel:

```
System -> Configuration -> GENERAL -> Design -> HTML Head -> Default Title
```

Comment: For Magento 2 (CE): *Admin panel > Store > Configuration > Design > HTML Head > Default Title*

Answer (score 5):

I make it work. Bellow is the solution:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="sendfriend"><title>Email to a Friend</title></action>
</reference>
```

and i edited sendfriend.xml file, and paste the above code

thanks